# Is there a CakePHP PayPal plugin?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

have not done any paypal integration so far.
Is any paypal plugin  available for cakephp where the user can pay via paypal account or credit card ?

Comment: This "question" is lacking any question marks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether there is a plugin and if there is I don't think I'd use it. This is one of those situations where it's well worth reading up on the API and doing it yourself. That way you'll have a good knowledge of the mechanism which is vital when it comes to testing (and you need to do a lot of that) and maintenance.

The API is very well documented (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home), although the sheer quantity of information can be overwhelming at first, and there is a sandbox for testing (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox).

I found the IPN sample code (https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples) to be a very useful starting point and, to be honest, there isn't much work required beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one it works with paypal WPP

https://bitbucket.org/chrispierce/paypalwpp-plugin-for-cakephp-2.x/overview

Answer (score 0):

There are a few implementation of CakePHP Paypal integrations out there including:

WebTechNick's Paypal IPN Plugin
http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/218/CakePHP_Paypal_IPN_Plugin

Or Google for: Paypal Direct Payment API Component, or Paypal Datasource

While some of these and other plugins do the job, at our website, kumutu.com, we use a custom built system as the Paypal API is well documented and as Leo suggests, our site is quite custom and knowing exactly how the payment system works is vital for us.

Comment: Nicks paypal plugin is for Cake 1, just in case, as Cake is now v2